# Some results not being shown but others are

Tags: 2013, search, publishing-site, search-results

In my site collection there are two sub sites.

In both sites there is "Pages" library.

In site1, under advanced setting for "Pages" library, include in search option is ON.
In site2, under advanced setting for "Pages" library, include in search option is OFF.

Site1 contain one page with title "My settings and libraries"
Site2 contain one page with title "Other settings"

When I search the word "settings" then it only shows site1 page "My settings and libraries" in search results and not site2 "Other settings".

If I turn on "include in search" option for Pages library in site2 then it appears in search results but then it also shows "AllItems.aspx" page in search results which I don't want. And that page is not appearing for site1.

I want both pages to appear in search results when I search for keyword "settings" but I don't want "Allitems.aspx" to appear in search results.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a query rule or result source which modifies the query to exclude allitems.aspx results.

```
 -filename:allitems.aspx
```

You can follow below link
http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-search-removing-junk.html